# Return output parameter from a stored procedure that includes several derived tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I return the count of the inner-most SELECT statement that marked by a star in the following stored procedure as an output parameter?

```
Create procedure MySp 
AS
Select  RowNumber,NewsId From 
(
    Select Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY FirstVisit) as 'RowNumber',NewsId From 
        (
            * Select Distinct NewsId,FirstVisit,PublishDate From VwNewsPack 
        ) as t
) as tt         
Where NewsId between 10 and 20
```

Comment: You should tag this with the RDBMS you're using rather than random words from your question.

Comment: No, not with *the word RDBMS*, but the *name of the RDBMS you're using*... Oracle? DB2? SQL Server? Postgres? The question cannot be answered unless we know which RDBMS this query is meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in one. That is, both assign to a variable and select a result set. It's one of the other.

You can return an extra column:

```
Select  RowNumber,NewsId,InnerCount From 
(
    Select Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY FirstVisit) as 'RowNumber', NewsId
      , COUNT(*) OVER () AS InnerCount
    From 
       (
        Select Distinct NewsId,FirstVisit,PublishDate From VwNewsPack 
    ) as t
) as tt         
Where NewsId between 10 and 20
```

If this isn't good enough, then you'll need a temp table for the inner select, and assign @@ROWCOUNT as the variable

Comment: thanks but your first solution didn't work. it forces me to use group by clause.

Comment: @Vahid Ghadiri: sorry, added the OVER clause now. Should work